# How to Alter Views Result in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, hooks

i've several list of products display on a Drupal block. I get the list of products using views module. Then, i've several pages dedicated for each product. Before the list of products display on a block, i need to check if the page for the product exist of not. if exist, i need to display the product as list, but if not exist, i don't want to display it as link.

Example:

I have pages:

Product/A for product A

Product/C for product C

I have products:

A

B

C

D

So, views result that display on the block, should be:

A -> as link

B -> not a link

C -> as link

D -> not a link

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think is to use a views field template file to be overridden.

Copy the template **sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-field.tpl.php** to your current enabled theme folder. Assuming that you have a block view "product-listing", you could rename it to **views-view-field--product-listing--block.tpl.php**.

Rescan template files in your view theming information. The file **views-view-field--product-listing--block.tpl.php** just created should be highlighted with bold. Now, you have an active custom field template for your block view.

[image]
Then, you can edit the template as you need. Here is a sample code:

```
<?php
 $alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$row->nid);
 if(drupal_valid_path($alias)){
     $url = url($alias);
?>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $row->node_title; ?></a>
<?php
}else{
?>
    <span><?php print $row->node_title; ?></span>
<?php
}
```

You can check if a page ( or path ) exists or not by using [drupal_valid_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_valid_path/7).