# want to display values of content type Article in a page

Tags: nodes

I have following fields in my content type Article:

Year: [have values - 2011,2012,2013,2014,2014,2016] 
Volume: [have values - 01,02,03,04,05] 
Issue: [have values - 1,2,3,4,5]

Title: [some value]
Description: [some text]

Now I want to display fields values like order below in views-view--archives--page.tpl.php

2013: [Volume3: Issue1, Issue 2, Issue 3] 2012: [Volume2: Issue1, Issue 2]

Comment: You set-up a view for this? You can rearrange the order, and opt to display the fields in-line within the Views UI. Or maybe I'm mis-understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a custom template or a custom theme function to output the fields, you will have to play with delta. You can also create multiple content types and link them with a relation field to create the hierarchy. You can also use a specific module that handles this kind of dimensional representation like tablefield or sheetnode.

Comment: could you please suggest any tutorial. I am new to Drupal. I know the basic but never done custom pages.

Comment: You can find here how to override a view template: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/51710/17992